# Echo mysql data in html table with foreach

Tags: php, sorting, date, datetime

I am retrieving records from db based on date and want to display all records according to the day. For example the record for monday should be below the monday heading and the record for tuesday should be below the tuesday heading. In my case sometimes some records from monday are visible below wednesday. How do I achieve this?

```
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>

<?php foreach($result as $r){
?>
<tr>
<?=$r->colname?>
</tr>

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Please show us the query, so we know what data we have to play with

Comment: Actually please show the real html as well, as this is obviously either wrong or Pseudo code

Comment: Posted you an example of some code. Please mark as right, if it was what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE stuff = "otherstuff"";    
$res=$conn->query($query);
     while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>".$row['date']."</th></tr>"; //here you get each date filtered by rows
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['stuff']."</td>"; //data1
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['otherstuff']."</td>"; //data2
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
}
```

I would recommend while() instead of foreach() when printing the content of a myslq query in a html5 table. It loops through the while() and generates a table for every row.

Your table should look like this:

```
Date    Stuff  Otherstuff  Morestuff
Monday  data1  data2       data3        //this one gets an own table
Tuesday XY     XY          XY           //this one gets the next table
```